# 2 equals select expression within select

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have to process my data by *Levenshtein* function.
In this case I'm using nested selection

```
SELECT levenshtein(a.param, b.param), *
FROM   (
         SELECT 5 fields
         FROM table t,
         JOIN x,
         JOIN y,
         GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
       ) a,
FROM   (
         SELECT 5 fields
         FROM table t,
         JOIN x,
         JOIN y,
         GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
       ) b,
```

is there a way to not duplicate inner `SELECT` ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html - `WITH` queries (aka. Common Table Expressions)

Comment: Thanks @Nicarus. That's works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple, thanks to @Nikarus for suggestion about WITH expression:

```
WITH subtable AS (
    SELECT 5 fields
     FROM table t,
     JOIN x,
     JOIN y,
     GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
SELECT levenshtein(a.param, b.param), *
FROM subtable a, subtable b
```